# iPhone flashlight app crashes when button is tapped fast

Tags: iphone, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice, flashlight

I got my flashligh app working perfectly. For some reason tho, everytime i tap on the flashlight button really fast, the app just freezes and doesnt do anything. It seems that its freezing when i call the AVCaptureSession stopRunning. Heres the code for my toggle flashlight method. I also want this method to eventually be called for a strobe feature.

```
- (void)toggleFlashlight{

  if (isTorchOn) {

   // Start session configuration
   [session beginConfiguration];

   [device lockForConfiguration:nil];    
   // Set torch to on
   [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];

   [device unlockForConfiguration];
   [session commitConfiguration];

  [session startRunning];


 }
 else {
  [session stopRunning];
  [session release]; 
  session = nil;

  session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

  // Create device input and add to current session
  AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
  [session addInput:input];

  // Create video output and add to current session      
  AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
  [session addOutput:output];
  [output release];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you actually understand what the code you've pasted above does, or did you copy it from somewhere else?

Because what you're doing is repeatedly asking iOS to create a video capture session, which then turns the light on. Creating a video capture session is very CPU/memory intensive. It was never designed or intended to be used rapidly - there's no 'normal' use-case in which a user would attempt to initiate multiple video capture sessions within seconds of each other. That's why you're getting your crashes.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shorter version you can now use to turn the LED on or off:

```
- (void)torchOnOff: (BOOL) onOff
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setTorchMode: onOff ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app revolves around AVCaptureSession, you should have one instance of AVCapture session running for the life of the app and simply toggle the torch in that session. You're over complicating things.
As mentioned, do NOT keep recreating the same session. This is a waste of resources. I recommend watching the WWDC '10 videos on the subject and looking through the Demo projects.